# Disable Jboss wildlfy welcome content

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am running wildfly using domain.sh and am unable to disable the Wildfly welcome content even after deploying a ROOT.war with joss-web.xml having 
    context-root / context-root

Comment: How are you setting the context-root?

Answer (score 6):

In domain/configuration/domain.xml:

Remove `<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>`

Remove

```
<handlers>
   <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

I disabled `welcome-root` and `welcome-content` in wildfly for web application by removing the following sections in the `..\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` file:

- remove location

  ```xml
  <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
  ```
- remove handler

  ```xml
  <handlers>
       <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
  </handlers>
  ```